# QListWidget disable mouseover highlight

Tags: qt, qt5, highlight, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

I have a QListWidget with several QListWidgetItems containing only text but with different background colors. By default the items become highlighted with a blue bar when I mouse over them. How can I disable the highlighting?

The code I use

```
//add spacer
QListWidgetItem *spacer = new QListWidgetItem("foo");
spacer->setBackgroundColor(QColor(Qt::gray));
spacer->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsEnabled);    //disables selectionable
ui->listWidget->addItem(spacer);
```

Thanks in advance.

[image]

`spacer` is the gray item with the name of the day

EDIT: added picture link (snipping tool Tool hides mouse, 6th item is highlighted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it with an custom item delegate overriding the `QStyledItemDelegate::paint` method.

```
void ActivitiesItemDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{

//determine if index is spacer
//TODO non-hacky spacer detection
bool spacer = false;
QString text = index.data().toString();
if(        ( text == "Monday")
        || ( text == "Tuesday")
        || ( text == "Wednesday")
        || ( text == "Thursday")
        || ( text == "Friday")
        || ( text == "Saturday")
        || ( text == "Sunday")
){
    spacer = true;
}

if(option.state & QStyle::State_MouseOver){
    if(spacer){
        painter->fillRect(option.rect, QColor(Qt::gray));
    }else{
        painter->fillRect(option.rect, QColor(Qt::white));
    }
    painter->drawText(option.rect.adjusted(3,1,0,0), text);
    return;
}

//default
QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the background on "hover" with Qt CSS, giving if you are using "gray" color:

```
spacer->setStylesheet("*:hover {background:gray;}");
```

Or styling the whole list as described in [Qt Style sheet examples](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qlistview)

```
QListView::item:hover {
    background: gray
}
```

Comment: I've got 2 background colors in the list. How can I define one background goes white and the other gray?

Comment: You can set a second color with 
QListView::item:alternate {
    background: #EEEEEE;
}

Comment: Using the alternate property isn't correct. When there are more activities under a spacer item, the colors become applied wrong. I'm looking for a way to set the hover background based on the QListWidgetItems text. Or maybe assign a custom type property to refer to from the QSS?